# Console.log does not show up when I run 'ionic run android -lc'

Tags: ionic-framework, console.log, package.json

My console.logs stopped showing up when I run 'ionic run android -lc'

It shows up when I hit it in the web browser.

Based on this [post](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/473) I have tried to add this line to my package.json file:

`"scripts": { "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build", "ionic:watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch" }`

but it gives me an error when I do a 'ionic build android' saying that 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized:

[image]

Here is my json.package, I highlighted what I added.

[image]

I tried to just remove the 'ionic-app-scripts' line in my package.json and it built correctly but it still did not log.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I just did a restart with a completely blank copy with 'ionic start moment blank' and I copied my www folder into the clean app.  Then I did a npm install and ran my app.  I am still not getting console.logs.  Could this somehow be happening because of my code in my www folder?  I don't understand this.  Any ideas?  I am running on Ionic 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an Ionic 2 app, you are missing the `@ionic/app-scripts` dependency from your `package.json`.

The latest is: `@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0"`

Example of a basic fully working ionic 2 package.json can be found in Ionic's conference app demo (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) :

```
{
  "name": "ionic-conference-app",
  "description": "Ionic Conference App",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5-201701112208",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  }
}
```

Take notice of the `@ionic/app-scripts` here.
To ensure a clean build, delete your current `node_modules` folder, and do a fresh `npm install` once you add the required dependencies.

Comment: Its actually an Ionic 1 app.  I added the script anyway and tried it but it is still not printing out the logs.